# Lists partition

Tags: java, list, split

I need to get 20% of the list of books and divide them into 5 folds. Currently, done the following

```
List<Integer> nonRatedBooks= allBookIDs;
Collections.shuffle(nonRatedBooks);
nonRatedBooks= nonRatedBooks.subList(0, (int) Math.ceil(nonRatedBooks.size() * 0.2));
int foldSize = (int) Math.ceil((float)nonRatedBooks.size() / 5);
List<List<Integer>> testFolds = Lists.partition(nonRatedBooks, foldSize);
```

The issue is that, when, for example I have a `nonRatedBooks.size()=6` (after getting the sublist), then `foldsize=2` and the `testFolds.size()=3`, because `Lists.partition` will divide into folds with size of 2. How can I do, so that there are always 5 folds?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That should works for you:

```
// get your 20% first
int chunk = nonRatedBooks.size() / 5;
List<List<Integer>> result = new LinkedList<List<Integer>>();
if (chunk < 1) {
    nonRatedBooks.stream().map(Lists::newArrayList).collect(Collectors.toCollection(() -> result));
} else {
    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
        int endIndex = i < 4 ? (i + 1) * chunk : nonRatedBooks.size();
        result.add(nonRatedBooks.subList(i * chunk, endIndex));
    }
}
```

Lists.partition is not the best solution in your case, since it will break your list depends on partition size which is vary.

Comment: is in the last chunk, when `i==4` will be the same size as nonRatedBooks? Or I am getting something wrong.

Comment: Well, when size of your 20% is 6 you can't split it for 5 equal chunks. So I split it for 5 groups like this: [1],[2],[3],[4],[5,6]. General logic here is that when the i == 4 you have "extended" chunk, so the last index will be equal to initial list size.

Answer (score 0):

A more bullet-proof way to divide an integer value into two parts by a fractional amount only needs one division:

```
int total = ...;
float ratio = ...;  // presumably from [0.0 .. 1.0] range
int part = Math.round(total * ratio);
int remaining = total - part;
```

This makes sure that `part` + `remaining` always sum up to `total`.